# .htaccess rule without changing filename/query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cross-domain

I have two domains - one forwarding successfully to the other. I also have a php script to create dynamic PDFs. My main site htaccess rule for that is roughly like...

```
RewriteRule (.*)poster.pdf(.*)  /pdfs.php?format=poster [L]  
RewriteRule (.*)leafletpdf(.*)  /pdfs.php?format=leaflet [L]
```

That worked perfectly for the main site - ie, the users saw and could download poster.pdf & leaflet.pdf but I had to add the full domain name to make it work for the redirected site, ie

```
RewriteRule (.*)poster.pdf(.*)  http://www.mydomain.com/pdfs.php?format=poster [L]  
RewriteRule (.*)leaflet.pdf(.*)  http://www.mydomain.com/pdfs.php?format=leaflet [L]
```

now the redirect site produces the PDFs properly but the user sees in the address bar...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/pdfs.php?format=leaflet[L]
```

...which makes it awkward to download and save the PDFs. I appreciate the security issues involved, and I have no problem with the domain name changing to the redirected-to site but is there any way I can keep the clean .pdf filenames?

Answer (score 1):

On your main site you could have this:

```
RewriteRule (.*)poster.pdf(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/poster.pdf [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)leaflet.pdf(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/leaflet.pdf [L,R=301]
```

And on your 2nd site you could have this:

```
RewriteRule (poster|leaflet)\.pdf /pdfs.php?format=$1 [L]
```